# Linking HTML element with onscroll, onchange doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a `div .progress` container change its width once the `div #myContact` reaches 100% height on scroll

I've tried linking the HTML element with onscroll, onchange or anything else but I don't seem to know what works.

```html
    <div onscroll="scrollProgress()" id="containter" class="snap">
        <div class="progress-container"> //this containter needs to change width
          <div class="progress-bar" id="myContact"></div> //when this one reaches 100% height
    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="scroll.js"> </script>
```

```css
#containter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px; // original setting is 100vh, this value is just for scrolling without me pasting all the other elemnts
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.progress-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  width: auto;
  background: #000;
  height: 0%;
  max-height: 100%
}
```

```
// Scroll function
  function scrollProgress() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('containter');
      var winScroll = elem.scrollTop;
      var height = elem.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("myContact").style.height = scrolled + "%";
};
    // Expand function

    /* When 'myContact' reaches 100% height then 'progres-container' expands left, and cover the entire screen*/

  function expandMe() {
    let trigger = document.getElementById('myContact').style.height;
    if (trigger = 100) {
      document.getElementById('progress').style.width = trigger + "%";
    }
  };
/* When 'myContact' reaches 100% height then 'progres-container' expands left,
 and cover the entire screen*/
```

Nothing really happens and also I have no errors.

Thank you so much!

Comment: IT seems you put assignment operator  `(trigger = 100)` instead of comparison `(trigger == 100)`

Comment: Nothing happens if i change that either.

Comment: it's not clear, I do not understand what you want to get.

Comment: The 'myContac' div is a scroll indicator. It starts from 0 to 100 as you scroll down. It's 'container' div remains 20% width all throughout the scrolling. I want that when 'myContac' reaches 100% height (user is at the bottom of the page) I want the 'container' div to change from 20% to 100% width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a pixel-perfect solution, but since you've got some mistakes in your code, an event listener should be bound to `window` object, then it will render as you need.
I added some visual effect to the width changing style.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      var winScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      var height = document.getElementById('container').scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("myContact").style.height = scrolled + "%";
      document.getElementById("myContact").parentElement.style.width =(scrolled >= 100) ? scrolled + "%" : "20%";
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.progress-container {
  position: fixed;
  background: #0f0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 1s;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  width: auto;
  background: #f00;
  height: 0%;
  max-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="snap">
        <div class="progress-container"> 
          <div class="progress-bar" id="myContact"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow! i was trying to make a separate function out of it haha thanks ill check if it works! it seems so from your snippet! thank you so much!